# Why does chlorine displace bromide

Tags: acid-base, stability

Found that chlorine will displace bromide, and iodide from their ion forms. According to my textbooks, this is because chlorine is more electronegative than bromine and iodine. However, the chloride ion is less stable than the bromide and iodide ions due to its larger charge density.

However, based on the acidity of HCl, HBr, HI, HCl is actually the least acidic one hinting that shouldn't charge density be a more important factor in determining stability than electronegativity and hence Br2 should displace Cl- instead of Cl2 displacing Br-?

Comment: You are dealing with redox reactions, and chlorine is a stronger oxidizing agent than bromine.

Comment: I guess you are considering reactions in solution. In your analysis you are forgetting the strength of the interaction of the ions with the solvent molecules and how this affect the relative stability of the ions, and its reactivity. For this reactions it is better to use  reduction potentials and its relation to reaction free energy $\Delta G^0_r$ as a guide to its reactivity.

Comment: In the case of the acidity of HCl, HBr and HI, you must consider the differences in solvatation energy betewee the ions and the molecues (this are related to the pK$_a$).

Comment: Finally, looking at a table of ionic radii (Wikipedia), $r(Cl^-) < r(Br^-) < r(I^-)$.  How can you explain that the charge density smaller for the smaller anion if you assume that the charge distribution is spherical and all the anions have the same charge (-1e)?

Comment: The smaller charge density was a typo, I have already changed it. But what is the difference between solvation energy and the interactions of the ions with the solvent molecules. Aren't they the same thing?